# I can not improve my note on the Google Page Speed

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

You can check my page speed [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fregalaunpuzzle.es%2F&tab=desktop)

I've done everything that Google has asked me, I even created the critical css.

Why google still saying that I am slow and that my css blocks?

Comment: You can start optimizing your images here https://tinypng.com/

Comment: My images are full optimized , if I do more it will lose quality

Comment: It says to “inline” the critical CSS, i.e. put it directly in a `<style>`. You haven’t done that (or any of the other things it’s still complaining about – why do you think you have? please list the steps you’ve taken in detail). Anyway, these are just advisory; you don’t have to do them if you don’t want to.

Comment: The critical.css is the first css visible to the first html visible. Y extract this css and put him on top of the head. Is the first css to load.

Comment: The following images served from rp-static.com should be combined into as few images as possible using CSS sprites